# R: Apply a Function on continuous column area of a Matrix

Tags: r

Hello I have the follwoing example matrix for my Problem:

```
              Cats       Dogs     Frogs
2016-12-02  0.9994518  1.025039  1.002728
2016-12-08  1.0490699  1.013039  1.027556
2016-12-05  1.0204215  1.006204  1.059064
```

My output should be Matrix which gives the Max in a column for each Point in time.

```
              Cats       Dogs     Frogs
2016-12-02  0.9994518  1.025039  1.002728
2016-12-08  1.0490699  1.025039  1.027556
2016-12-05  1.0490699  1.025039  1.059064
```

The number of columns and rows can vary. I tried a lot of `repeat Loops` and `apply(..)` funtions but nothing works.

I really appreciate any help you can provide !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cummax` after looping through the columns with `apply` and specifying `MARGIN = 2`

```
apply(m1, 2, cummax)
#                Cats     Dogs    Frogs
#2016-12-02 0.9994518 1.025039 1.002728
#2016-12-08 1.0490699 1.025039 1.027556
#2016-12-05 1.0490699 1.025039 1.059064
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(0.9994518, 1.0490699, 1.0204215, 1.025039, 1.013039, 
1.006204, 1.002728, 1.027556, 1.059064), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("2016-12-02", "2016-12-08", "2016-12-05"), c("Cats", "Dogs", 
"Frogs")))
```

Comment: or `matrixStats::colCummaxs(m1)`